# I am not getting the byte values?

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm not able to get the right output when I do the following code. look at the comments for what I'm trying to print.

I did the code based on what I've been learning so far, but I'm still not getting the right output.

So any suggestions? What have I done, so I'm able to fix the problem.
When I print(A), I'm not getting `0100 0001`, but it prints `49d` or `49` sometimes

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char getBit(unsigned char c, int n)
{
    return ((c & (1 << n)) >> n);
}
unsigned char setBit(unsigned char c, int n)
{
    c = c | (1 << n);
    return c;
}

unsigned char clearBit(unsigned char c, int n)
{
    c = c & (~(1 << n));
    return c;
}

void printBits(unsigned char c)
{
    printf("The bit of the character you inputed is %x \n", c);
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char a = 'A';
    printBits(a);
    putchar('\n');

    a = setBit(a, 2);
    a = setBit(a, 3);
    printBits(a);  //should print 0100 0001, but it prints 49
    putchar('\n');

    a = clearBit(a, 2);
    printBits(a);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: How `arr` is relevant to this? Please post [mcve] with the emphasis on "Minimal".

Comment: Why would you expect `printBits` to print anything other than a hexadecimal number anyway? This is what you ask it to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current solution prints the value of `c` as a hexadecimal number using `printf()`. Since there is no printf format specifier to print a number in binary representation, we'll have to write our own solution.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void printBits(byte c)
{
    for (unsigned i = CHAR_BIT; i;) { // count from the with of a char
                                      // in bits down to 1
        putchar(c & 1 << --i  // test the i-th bit (1-based)
            ? '1'         // if true (different form 0) evaluates to '1'
            : '0'         // else evaluates to '0'
        );
        if (CHAR_BIT == 8 && i % 4 == 0)  // if we use 8-bit-bytes and just
                                          // finished printing the higher nibble
            putchar(' ');  // insert a seperator between the nibbles
    }
}
```

... ftw!

No-nonsense version:

```
void printBits(byte c)
{
    for (unsigned i = CHAR_BIT; i;) {
        putchar(c & 1 << --i ? '1' : '0');
        if (CHAR_BIT == 8 && !(i % 4))
            putchar(' ');
    }
}
```

`

```
unsigned char a = 'A';
printBits(a);  // should print 0100 0001
putchar('\n');

a = setBit(a, 2); 
a = setBit(a, 3); 
printBits(a);  // should print 0100 1101
putchar('\n');

a = clearBit(a, 2);
printBits(a);  // should print 0100 1001
putchar('\n'
```

Comment: Code only answer with "wtf" in the middle? Does not qualify as a good one by SO standards.

Comment: @EugeneSh. typo. should have been a ftw!

Comment: @Swordfish As an aside and hijacking the question, does 'A' not mean 41 decimal (101001 binary)? If so, why is 01000001 printed?

Comment: @fotang: In ASCII `'A'` is `65` and thus `01000001b`

Comment: @Swordfish Oh true. Thanks.